# How to make an xsd element as Mandatory element

Tags: xsd

In the below xsd, I want to make the `EDI_DC` element as mandatory.I tried by using `minOccurs="1"` and `nillable="false"` but it is not working.

please suggest me any other way here to make this element as mandatory.

xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:nxsd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/nxsd"
            xmlns:tns="http://TargetNamespace.com/sdg"
            targetNamespace="http://www.oracle.com/ias/processconnect"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
            nxsd:stream="chars"
            nxsd:version="NXSD">

  <xsd:element name="Root-Element">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">

        <xsd:element name="EDI_DC"  nxsd:startsWith="EDI_DC" >
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="tabnam" 
                           type="xsd:string" 
                           nxsd:style="fixedLength"
                           nxsd:length="4" 
                           />
              <xsd:element name="mandt" 
                           type="xsd:string" 
                           nxsd:style="fixedLength"
                           nxsd:length="3" 
                           />
              <xsd:element name="docnum" 
                           type="xsd:string" 
                           nxsd:style="fixedLength"
                           nxsd:length="16" 
                           />
              <xsd:element name="docrel" 
                           type="xsd:string" 
                           nxsd:style="fixedLength"
                           nxsd:length="4" 
                           />

              <xsd:element name="EDI_DCeol" 
                           type="xsd:string"  
                           nxsd:style="terminated"
                           nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

        <xsd:element name="E2EDL20"  nxsd:startsWith="E2EDL20">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="segnam_ver" type="xsd:string"
                           nxsd:style="fixedLength" 
                           nxsd:length="23"
                           />
              <xsd:element name="mandt" type="xsd:string" 
                           nxsd:style="fixedLength"
                           nxsd:length="3" />
              <xsd:element name="docnum" type="xsd:string" 
                           nxsd:style="fixedLength"
                           nxsd:length="16" />

              <xsd:element name="E2EDL20EOL" type="xsd:string" 
                           nxsd:style="terminated"
                           nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>


      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? The minOccurs is the way to make it mandatory as far as I know.

Comment: EDI_DC is a required component in a required sequence in the content model of Root-Element.  (So is E2EDL20, for that matter.)  What is making you think you need to do anything to make it more required than it already is?

Comment: In the input xml if EDI_DC is not present that time also this schema is not giving error.

Comment: is this issue with nxsd:startsWith="EDI_DC" ?

Comment: It [validates](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=a861025d-9e71-4f77-aef4-53cfdb4f82c5-xsdvalidation) if you have `EDI_DC`. It [does not validate](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=7aadcfd6-1ecc-446e-a70d-90281e1a4b1c-xsdvalidation) if you don't, as expected. If it doesn't behave as expected, check the other tools you are using (Oracle Native Format) and add the appropriate tags so that users who know about *nsxd* may be able to find this question

Comment: You say *if EDI_DC is not present* [in the input] *this schema is not giving error*.  Hard to believe; if you can provide a small but complete working example (i.e. a full schema document and a full XML instance that illustrates the problem), people may be able to help.  As it is, the most plausible explanation is that you are misinterpreting the behavior of your software.